# Xamarin Android: font not picked up

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to apply Google's Quicksand font (https://fonts.google.com/?query=quicksand) to my Xamarin Android app.

I've added `quicksand_bold.ttf`, `quicksand_light.ttf`, `quicksand_medium.ttf` and `quicksand_regular.ttf` to the `Resources\font` folder, with a build type of AndroidResource.

I have also added a file called `quicksand.xml` to the same folder. This contains the text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font android:font="@font/quicksand_regular"
          android:fontStyle="normal"
          android:fontWeight="400"
          app:font="@font/quicksand_regular"
          app:fontStyle="normal"
          app:fontWeight="400" />
    <font android:font="@font/quicksand_bold"
          android:fontStyle="normal"
          android:fontWeight="700"
          app:font="@font/quicksand_bold"
          app:fontStyle="normal"
          app:fontWeight="700" />
    <font android:font="@font/quicksand_medium"
          android:fontStyle="normal"
          android:fontWeight="500"
          app:font="@font/quicksand_medium"
          app:fontStyle="normal"
          app:fontWeight="500" />
    <font android:font="@font/quicksand_light"
          android:fontStyle="normal"
          android:fontWeight="300"
          app:font="@font/quicksand_light"
          app:fontStyle="normal"
          app:fontWeight="300" />
  </font-family>
</font-family>
```

And finally I've applied the theme `Theme="@style/MyTheme"` to my main Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/quicksand</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I've been following the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/fonts. I'm assuming that the `@font/quicksand` element directs the system to the `quicksand.xml` file.

I would have thought that these steps would be sufficient for the font to be picked up as part of my default style, but this isn't happening.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using custom fonts can be tricky in Android, it can cause big RAM usage.

One of the easiest way to add custom font to your app is using [Calligraphy-xamarin](https://github.com/mikescandy/Calligraphy-xamarin) which is Xamarin binding of [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy).

Here is quick tutorial:

First `Install-Package CallygraphyXamarin`, then add following to your Activity

```
protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context newBase)
{
    base.AttachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.Wrap(newBase));
}
```

And finally use custom font like so:

```
<TextView
    fontPath="fonts/myfont.ttf"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello world!" />
```

If you want to set default font for your app, add (for example) `MyApplication.cs` to your project with following content:

```
[Application]
public class MyApplication : Application
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public MyApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        CalligraphyConfig.InitDefault(
            new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()               
            .SetDefaultFontPath("fonts/myfont.ttf")
            .SetFontAttrId(Resource.Attribute.fontPath)
            .Build()
         );
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks extremely promising. I'm trying it out now.